# Joomla logout button redirects to old domain (from which migrated earlier)

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I am working on a Joomla project, basically a LMS based on moodle and integrated with Joomdle component. All worked fine until I migrated the whole site along with database to new domain by using Akeeba Backup & Restore component.

Everything went great. Site migrated successfully, but now the problem is that when I click on `Logout` button after logging in joomla front end, it takes me back to old domain. I don't know what's going wrong. I have checked `configuration.php` everything looks good. I have installed another module `BT Login Module` for creating a popup window for user to login/register.

Where else should I check? Someone please tell me where else could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Also performed a Search/Replace script run on my joomla database. Replaced old domain with the new one. 245 cells  were changed. But still getting same problem. Logout redirects to old domain.

Comment: Solved. Actually I had this error in Joomdle configuration: `Joomla URL seems to be misconfigured in Joomdle auth plugin in Moodle`. So I logged in to moodle as super admin and changed the Joomla URL from old to new domain at `Site Administration > Plugins > Authentication > Joomdle > Joomla URL`